# SQL order by date and time not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to order the messages by time and date, but its not working:
here is my code:

```html
$sql="SELECT id, message, sender, recipient, date, time, IF(recipient = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"].", 'received', 'sent') AS direction
        FROM message
        WHERE
            (recipient = $friend_id OR sender = $friend_id)
            AND id > $last_message_id ORDER BY time AND date ASC";
```

Comment: use comma not `AND` -> `ORDER BY time ASC, date ASC` or `ORDER BY time, date` (since `ASC` is default)

Comment: seeing your comment in the other answers - `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`. Then your query is failing. You can use a `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to see your error message.

Comment: Yep, I removed that comment because I realised I still had the AND in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU NEED TO PUT `ASC` WITH BOTH COLUMN LIKE THIS:-

```
$sql="SELECT id, message, sender, recipient, date, time, IF(recipient = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"].", 'received', 'sent') AS direction
        FROM message
        WHERE
            (recipient = $friend_id OR sender = $friend_id)
            AND id > $last_message_id ORDER BY time ASC, date ASC";
```

Comment: the `ASC` is not really necessary as [`The default is ascending order; this can be specified explicitly using the ASC keyword.`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) so they could just do `ORDER BY time, date` where the issue was `AND` vs `,`

Comment: [I DON'T KNOW WHAT WE ARE YELLING ABOUT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pdWAcK6Eh8)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off slightly. Sorting specifications for multiple columns need to be comma separated. Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT id, message, sender, recipient, date, time, IF(recipient = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"].", 'received', 'sent') AS direction
        FROM message
        WHERE
            (recipient = $friend_id OR sender = $friend_id)
            AND id > $last_message_id ORDER BY time ASC, date ASC";
```

As a side note, `ASC` is the default sort order, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `ORDER BY time ASC, date ASC`, assuming both are of appropriate data types; it doesn't always work out as desired if they are string types.